# Android browsers keyboard opens/closes on last input field focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, android-browser

I'm getting some odd behaviour in the Chrome browser on HTC One and Galaxy S5.
I click on an input field to enter some data and the keyboard opens and immediately closes again.
I've noticed it only happens on the last available input field on my pages.

Has anyone encountered this issue before?

It works fine on the iPhone and desktop browsers.

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Ok...so it looks like it has something to do with android browsers redrawing the DOM whenever the keyboard appears. I have $(window).resize() function that is getting called each time the keyboard appears in this case. I may just switch it to use $(window).load().

Comment: I faced the same issue in Android browsers, and fixed in by fixing $(window).resize() function. Thanks a lot.